# How to process YAML file ? (Data mining)

Tags: python, yaml, weka, data-mining, orange

I want to know that can i process .yaml file directly with any Data Mining IDE?
I have the IPL cricket data(.yaml) with ball to ball information so i need to do first pre-processing  to convert it to player wise information. 
For that i need help.
How to process it and manipulate it?

Answer (score 0):

YAML is a too broad purpose format. It can fully represent graphs.

Whatever tool you need, **you will need to specify the transformation**. Point-and-click analysis of YAML files will not work (or only cover a single, specific case - probably not yours then).

So you may just as well do it outside the tool, with your favorite programming language.